# expo push notifications not working in release mode

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-push-notifications

I have developed a react-native application using expo. and implemented push notification all working fine in development but when I release the application it does not working. no notification are receiving in the release mode.

Comment: On which device are you facing the issue, Android or IOS ? When sending the request for notification are you calling FCM?

Comment: on iOS . release are not wokting . not even in test flight

Comment: As you have not provided any code for the invocation of the notification, there could be only 2 reasons that can I think of:
1. You have not called the APN's API instead, you called the expo API.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided any code for the invocation of the notification, there could be only 2 reasons that can I think of:

1. If you are using **firebase as a BaaS**, the **Cloud Messaging** is not configured or the server key is mismatching.
2. You have not called the **APN's** API instead, you called the expo API. If that's the case, call the **APN's API** as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/#apns-server).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, setting the projectId solved it:

```
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications'
import Constants from 'expo-constants'

token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync(
            {
                projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
            }
        )).data
```